# Object lifetime of local placed into a new array

Tags: c++

Say I do this:

```
A* p = nullptr;

{
    const A a = A(2);
    p = new A[3];
    p[0] = a;
}
```

What, if anything, prevents `a`'s destructor from being called

```
   p[0] = a;
} <- here ?
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`a`'s destructor *is* called there. However, `p[0] = a` makes a *copy* of `a`. The copy's lifetime continues until `p` is subsequently destroyed and deallocated by `delete[]`.

Comment: I think this is the right answer, but I don't think `p[0] = a` makes a copy in C++11

Comment: @frickskit It does make a copy. It's like `A a2; a2 = a;`

Comment: @frickskit It's a copy assignment, not a copy construction. Still a copy, if you ask me.

Answer (score 0):

The destructor of *A* will be called in C++98 but `p[0] = a;` will copy *A* in the array element.

In C++11 *A* will be moved to p[0] and the destructor of A (that is now strip out) will be called (probably optimized away).

Comment: Why, `nullptr` point to C++11 in use, and variable _a_ will go out of scope, is the perfect move candidate.

Comment: if it's moved, then what is being destroyed? will `p[0]` be dangling outside of the scope?

Comment: By the way, I don't see the copy constructor being called (I wrote code and logged it), so I think @NetVipeC is right.

Comment: If the compiler can be certain that there is no way that the variable be used after, it will make the move.

Comment: @frickskit, `const A a = A(2);` will almost certainly do copy elision (and if not that, a move if possible). `p[0] = a;` is an assignment, not copy construction.

Comment: @frickskit: Even a moved-from object will be destroyed.